# Simple linq2sql query to display in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal reports and would like to to display sql data on a crystal report using linq2sql. So far i am just trying to display one field (tripNo) with no luck. My error is the data source object is invalid. Here is my code.

```
private void runstuff()
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var test = (from s in db.trips
                        select s.tripNo).First();

            CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
            cr1.SetDataSource(test);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `CrystalReport1` really only have one field in it name `tripNo`?

Comment: Yes just the one field for now to make it simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.config file needed this line

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while since I've used Crystal. However, the problem seems to be the type of 'test'. Crystal probably doesn't know what to do with this. You might want to try this. Note, I've removed the First() method so that a list of rows are returned and then I convert this to a List of entities. Crystal should be able to handle this.

```
var test = (from s in db.trips
            select s.tripNo).ToList();

            CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
            cr1.SetDataSource(test);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this does not compile but i tried changing ).single()l to ).ToList(); and now I get column does not belong to table trips

Comment: still get Column '' does not belong to table trips. Could i be missing some thing on the actual report viewer control?

Comment: Changed to: select new { s.tripNo}).ToList();    Now I am getting no source available

Comment: I added the line cr1.VerifyDatabase(); and its erroring there saying the report filename was empty. Any help???

Comment: Adding this: select new { s.tripNo}).ToList(); plus the line in my answer for the app file solved the problem. Thanks for the help