# Crystal Report Error: The data source object is invalid

Tags: crystal-reports, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-5.0

Am Trying to Print out a student Identity Card using crystal report but all what i could get was this error popping up `The data source object is invalid.`

Guys please help me to check on this code if am making any mistake...

this is the model

```
public class CardModel
{
        // Properties
        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public Sex Gender { get; set; }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }

        public byte[] SecuritySign { get; set; }

        public byte[] StudentPhoto { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public static class CardModelExtention
{
    public static CardModel ToCardModel(this Student identity)
    {
        return new CardModel
        {
            Id = identity.Id,
            FirstName = identity.FirstName,
            MiddleName = identity.MiddleName,
            Surname = identity.Surname,
            StudentPhoto = identity.Photo.RawPhoto,
            SecuritySign = identity.SecuritySignature.RawSignature,
            Gender = identity.Sex,
            ExpiryDate = identity.ExpiryDate,
            Department = identity.Department.DepartmentName,
            RegistrationNo = identity.RegistrationNo
        };
    }
}
```

and here is the service am using to pull the information from database

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    ERMUoW _ow;
    public StudentService()
    {
        _ow = new ERMUoW();
    }

    public CardModel GetStudentById(Guid id)
    {
        CardModel obj3 = new CardModel();

            Student student  = _ow.Students.GetAllIncluding(new Expression<Func<Student, object>>[] { st => st.Photo, st => st.Signature, st => st.SecuritySignature, st => st.Department }).Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

            var cardInfo = student.ToCardModel();

        return cardInfo;
    }
}

public interface IStudentService
{
    CardModel GetStudentById(Guid id);
}
```

This is it and everything around here is working fine and am getting the data very well but when I send it to the method in my contrller that generate the identity card I  get that error message

this is the code that generate the card using crytal report

```
public ActionResult PrintCard(Guid id)
    {
        var student = _studentCardService.GetStudentById(id);

        ReportDocument read = new ReportDocument();

        read.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rpt_StudentCard.rpt"));

        read.SetDataSource(student);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        try
        {
            Stream stream = read.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "StudentIdentityCard.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I will really Appreciate your help thank you...

Comment: try getting a list of `List<CarModel>` instead of 1 CarModel entity and handle items in rpt file. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10368772/1166597)

Comment: Okay that is working then how can I get One Item to Display... How do I handle that as you said?

Comment: nothing special in handling your report but normal work.

On your `report details section(s)` drag-drop your desired fields/ Formula fields/ Parameters, arrange them the way you need as a list layout, card layout as you feel fit and you may hit preview to see sample result based on your input or criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The data source have to be a List of elements... not a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you set NOCOUNT ON